# Invalid code in frequently viewed question

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

[This PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists) is highly upvoted and frequently visited, yet the question's example code is not valid PHP. The invalid component of the code does not affect the question; in fact for such a frequently visited question it's a distraction.

Another user previously edited the question to have valid code. The edit did not change the question being asked or invalidate any answers. However a moderator rolled back the edit.

[This meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) indicates that fixing errors in questions' code is fine if the errors are not relevant to the question. Why would this question (particularly as it's so visited) be left with incorrect code when the errors in the code have no real bearing on the question?

Comment: Maybe a better explanation of the edit would help? "reassigned array variables" doesn't really say much useful, and certainly doesn't convey that "The edit did not change the question being asked or invalidate any answers."

Comment: I'm not sure here, the moderator performing the rollback is also a frequent answerer on the PHP tag, so they probably had an understanding of what the question was about and how the edit affected existing answers, if they had time to read them

Comment: It's worth noting that the rollback was done *prior* to that specific user being elected as a moderator. The rollback was performed in February 2020, however, they were elected in 2021 and were not called up until March  2022.

Comment: You state that the code is invalid, however, an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440508/20299830) states it is but would just result in the array containing one value. Could the behaviour of PHP changed since the question was asked, or is one of you wrong in their statements? *If* the syntax was correct when it was asked, then I actually feel that it *should* be left as it is.

Comment: @ThomA invalid may have been a little too strong a description. It won't throw an exception. But it's not correct to do arrays like that, and seems like a distraction to the main question

Comment: So it's just *bad* code? Then I don't see the benefit of changing it, @jla . Especially as such a change *does* invalidate at least one of the answers (which is also the accepted answer).

Comment: Fair enough. I found it distracting on such a highly viewed question, and seeing the rollback made me wonder why someone went out of their way to leave the mistake in

Comment: I believe that that code might in fact be **intentional**, probably the asker wanted to check the behaviour that PHP would exhibit when given code like that and they were trying to figure out what value the array keeps and whether it is consistent, etc.

Comment: Why does the question's code have to be valid? People ask questions about invalid code all the time. Fixing it is kind of the point of the site existing.

Comment: @TylerH: "Why does the question's code have to be valid? People ask questions about invalid code all the time." - But the referenced question is not ABOUT invalid code. In such questions it is better to have the code being valid and being free from .. "unusual" things.

Answer (score 8):

From reading the answers, it appears that the code provided isn't invalid, it more likely just "bad" code. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440508/20299830), which is the accepted answer, specifically references that the question assigns a value to the same key twice and explains what happens when that is done.

As a result the change that was made, back in [2020](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2440506/6), would in fact invalidate at least one answer and, as you mention in the question, edits that invalidate answers are frowned upon. As the code is *valid*, just likely doesn't do what the OP expects (which is also likely a reason they are asking the question), it appears to be irrelevant at best that the same key is assigned the same value. I don't really see how it's distracting, as (again) at least one answer addresses it and actually provides helpful information about the scenario which could help future readers.

Comment: "would in fact invalidate at least one answer" - Even after the removing duplicate key from the question's code, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440508/20299830) won't be invalid: Its **main content** with `if` code remains valid. What would be incorrect is the **side note** ("By the way, you are assigning a value with the key say twice"). But the very side note should NOT be in the answer post in the first place. Such notes should be in the comments, which could easily be removed after fixing the referenced content.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's something that should go in a comment myself, @Tsyvarev . Comments are, as always, "3rd class citizens" and that information could easily disappear from them comments. Being in the answer means that information remains, and it is relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

The whole question is about the **single** key and **two possible values** for it. And the intention of the current code seems to be

> The key could be assigned with `bla` **or** with `omg`.

That is, assigning "correct" value `omg` but for a **different** key, as in the suggested edit, would only confuse the readers.

If the purpose is to save both code and the author intention, I find that it is better to provide **3 snippets** of code, with comments describing what should be returned by the check:

```
$something = array('say' => 'bla'); // Check should return true
```

```
$something = array('say' => 'omg'); // Check should return true
```

```
$something = array('say' => 'neither'); // Check should return false
```